# How can I run Microsoft Azure DocumentDB locally?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I use a Mac and mostly work on Node.js projects. I would like to try out DocumentDB to compare it against MongoDB. Is there anyway to run a local instance of Azure DocumentDB without going thru the hassles of setting up a real account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Since Nov 16, 2016 ([announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-emulator-for-local-development-and-dotnet-core-support/)), you can [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator) the new official DocumentDB emulator.

Comment: The OP said they "use a Mac" but the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#system-requirements) on that page say: "Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016, or Windows 10". The [docker image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-docker) doesn't even work on non-windows: "The Azure Cosmos DB Emulator can be run on Docker for Windows. The Emulator does not work on Docker for Oracle Linux." I haven't been able to find any way to do this with a local instance of CosmosDB on a non-windows machine. :(

Answer (score 3):

as astaykov mentioned, there is no local instance of DocumentDB available at this time. Your options are to either sign up for an Azure Trial at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/ or you can send mail to askdocdb AT microsoft. We are currently running a program where we provide free database accounts (no signup required) for evaluation periods.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any future plans to run it locally?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DocumentDB emulator now. Just released yesterday.

Get it here: [Use the Azure DocumentDB Emulator for development and testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a local development environment might ship by end of this year (2016) or sooner.

More information is at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6328798-standalone-local-instance

Comment: They have now started development on it. It's happening!

Answer (score 1):

Still not a local solution, but if you sign up for the 'dev essentials' program, you get a 25 USD/month credit for free, forever. If you're a little bit careful this allows to do enough dev/test work in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported with **[DocumentDB emulator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator)**

you can download from the above link. Based on **[Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-emulator-for-local-development-and-dotnet-core-support/)**,

> The DocumentDB Emulator provides a high-fidelity emulation of the
>   DocumentDB service. It supports identical functionality as Azure
>   DocumentDB, including support for creating and querying JSON
>   documents, provisioning and scaling collections, and executing stored
>   procedures and triggers. You can develop and test applications using
>   the DocumentDB Emulator, and deploy them to Azure at global scale by
>   just making a single configuration change.

```
// Connect to the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator running locally
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://localhost:8081"),"C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
```

You can read more about [`how to setup Azure CosmosDB on local with VSCODE.`](http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2018/03/setting-up-azure-cosmos-db-with-visual.html)